# Prepend value to textarea

Tags: jquery, html

I have created this JQuery code to prepend a textarea input

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;

    $('#standard_response').on('change', function() {
        var sequence = $(this).val();
        //Check each object in the data array
        $.each(data, function( index, obj ) {
            if(obj.sequence === sequence) {
                $('#description').prepend( obj.response );
            }
        });
        //$('#standard_response').select2('val', '');
    });
});
```

but it only works when the textarea is empty.

i want it to add the text at the end of the textarea where the cursor was left

i have also tried:

```
$('#description').text( $('#description').text() + obj.response );

$('#description').text( $('#description').val() + obj.response );
```

but neither of these work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use val

```
var value = $('#description').val();
$('#description').val(value + obj.response );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#description').val( $('#description').val() + obj.response );
```

Comment: The question was about prepending text which suggests they wanted to insert new text at the beginning. The solution that worked for me was simialr but with the insertion order the opposite way round i.e. "$('#description').val( obj.response + $('#description').val());

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `#description` is the `textarea` element, you should use `val()` to set its value. You can provide a function to the method to prepend the easily append new value. Try this:

```
if (obj.sequence === sequence) {
    $('#description').val(function(i, v) {
        return obj.response + v;
    });
}
```